# How to check wether any folder exist on root of project or not?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-scripts

I am working on NPM script , i have folder named scripts where all my script has been placed . I want to check is there any folder named docs at root of project, if yes delete it.Else do other task . I am using fs-extra for working with directories.

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const dir = 'docs';
try {
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.unlinkSync(dir);
        console.log("Unwanted folder remove from boilerplate")
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
}
```

I tried this script , but it did nothing .

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help with the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra), you can use [removeSync](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/remove-sync.md#removesyncpath) method:

> Removes a file or directory. The directory can have contents. If the path does not exist, silently does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain **File System** from **Node API** like this.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.stat('PATH_TO_DIRECTORY', (err, stat) => {

  // Directory not found
  if (err) throw err

  // The current path is not a directory
  if (!stat.isDirectory()) throw "Not a directory"

  doYourStuff()
})
```